# Repeated login issue SQL Server 2008 R2 (SSIS)

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssis, logins, audit, dts

I'm trying to figure out an issue I'm currently having with an SQL Server connection - there has been a few issues with timeouts on a SSIS package, where it has failed a login attempt - however as far as I am aware, the job *should* only connect once (Fwiw: The SSIS task is a simple datamart query - it returns results from a complex query into a single table on another server - the whole task runs in 40 seconds when executed by clicking on the DTSX package).

The SQL Server agent is running on the destination server, and the connection is through a local network - I am remote from this network, but both machines can see each other on 192.168.1.##.

I'm trying to understand what would cause the login to happen more than one time for this single task - I have set up Full login auditing on the destination server, and the logs look like this (I have truncated the screenshot to hide names, however in all of these logins it was the same username):

[image]

It also shows multiple logins for the `NetworkService` account when I remotely connect to the SQL Server - so not just limited to this DTS task, just more pronounced here - and there is no specific issue with timeouts elsewhere!